# Using OR in LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can't seem to find this asked anywhere. How do you use OR operator within LINQ expressions?

For example something that follows this logic:

```
var links = links.Where(l => l.First() == '/' OR.. == '//').ToList();
```

Comment: Linq extension methods are just C#.  use the `||` operator.

Comment: You need to use the c# or operator ||

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`OR` is `||`

```
var links = links.Where(l => l.First() == '/'|| l.First() == '//').ToList();
```

By the way, `AND` is `&&`

Answer (score 3):

```
var links = links.Where(l => l.First() == '/'|| l.First() == '//').ToList();
```

this will solve

Answer (score 1):

```
var links = links.Where(l => l.First() == '/' || ... == '//').ToList();
```